# Use flask-sqlalchemy with pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with pyCharm, and been trying to install the sqlalchemy package to help me connect to my mysql db. I've run

```
pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

which completed successfully after downloading a bunch of files, but still the library isn't available when I do:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

I'm pretty new to python and all this stuff, and I can't figure out what to do. Installing flask was easy because pyCharm sort of did that for me, is there any way to do something similar with this?

**EDIT:** I have managed to do this by opening pyCharm's preferences, then going to Project Interpreter, which displays all of the installed modules. Then simply click the + button at the bottom, and search for the required module... PyCharm did everything for me from that point.

Comment: flask-sqlalchemy != sqlalchemy You have to install SQLAlchemy, not the SQLAlchemy module for Flask.

Answer (score 11):

What works great when working with pyCharm and dependencies is to create a `requirements.txt` at the root of the project and add all of the packages required for your project.

With that pyCharm will auto-detect the `requirements.txt` file and ask you if you want to download the dependencies automatically.

In your case you could have tried to create a `requirements.txt` with:

```
flask
flask-sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Simpler way of declaring dependencies :)

Comment: 3 years laters and still helping people. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a project folder, setup a virtualenv and install flask-sqlalchemy:

```
mkdir test
virtualenv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

Then in pycharm open test folder as a new project. You should be able to call :

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: The problem is I already have a project I've been working on for a while, I was just looking for a way to add sqlalchemy to it...

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also encountered a similar issue and would like to share how I resolved it:

Step 1: In your PyCharm IDE, navigate to **"File" -> "Settings" -> "Project: Your_Project_Name" -> "Python Interpreter"**.

Step 2: Click on the **"+"** button and search for **"Flask-SQLAlchemy"**.

Step 3: Select "Flask-SQLAlchemy" from the search results and click "Install" to download and install the package.

By following these steps, I am able to successfully install the Flask-SQLAlchemy package in my PyCharm IDE. I hope that my approach can assist novice Python developers who may be facing similar challenges.

Thanks!